# Prevent atom editor from deleting last blank lines when saving a file

Tags: atom-editor

The editor I used previously do not remove automatically blank lines at the end of a file when saving.

The atom editor does it.

Problem is, if I open such a file with atom, do some changes, undo the changes and save, the file will be seen as changed by git, only because of these removed blank lines.

I know I could each time tell git to ignore the change, but it's annoying and I'd prefer not to interfere with git.

Does anyone know a way of preventing atom to automatically delete the blank lines at the end of a file when it saves it? I can't find it in the preferences nor any package providing this feature.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Go to: Settings / Packages
2. Find package whitespace
3. Click settings in whitespace package
4. Uncheck 'Ensure Single Trailing Newline'

Comment: Thank you very much! I had been struggling so long and couldn't find it!